# A monotonic sequence is always convergent in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (Proof?)

Tags: real-analysis

$\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is defined as $\overline{\mathbb{R}}:=\mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty,\infty\}$. If $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is monotonic (increasing) the $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_{n+1}\geq a_n$.

I have to proof that the sequence is always convergent in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. I'm not sure how to do this... 
I think that a couple of hints will help me.

Comment: Do you know that a bounded monotonic sequence always converges?

Comment: Yes, that I have proved.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider two cases: when the sequence is bounded, and when it is not.

Comment: Case 1: bounded. I have done this one. 
Case 2: Unbounded. I'm thinking to reuse the proof in the bounded case and just define $a:=\sup{A}=+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But I suggest that you actually prove that if the sequence is unbounded, then its limit is $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I have to proof that for my own understand. I'm trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We know that any bounded monotonic sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ and so it converges in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. If $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded then it simply converges to $\infty \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Yes, this i have thought about and understand. But I still do not know how to do the proof itself :-)

Comment: You could prove the limit is infinity by showing that it cannot be any finite number. A simple proof by contradiction would suffice.